# Django and tinymcs: getting list of image files using external_image_list_url

Tags: django, tinymce

I am trying to get external_image_list_url to work with tinymcs and Django. My understanding is that the user will be able to see a list of his or her images when clicking on the image icon (the one with the tree). From here an image can be selected and inserted.

Am I right that it is the icon with the tree? It's the one called "image". The one called "insertimage" doesn't work at all - the icon is not displayed. It and insertfile are the only ones that aren't displayed. I'm Ok with that unless I need it for this list functionality.

First I am trying just to get any image to appear in a list. I have done the following:

Created myexternallist.js and placed it where I keep my other JS files. I can access these other files via src = "/media/js/filename.js" because of my django settings. But is this also what I should put for:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    external_image_list_url : "/media/js/myexternallist.js",
    ... })
```

In this file it says:

```
var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(["Logo 1", "/media/js/photo.jpg"],);
```

photo.jpg is in the same folder as myexternallist.js

I have also tried just "photo.jpg" and various other combinations. Not sure if my issue has to do with my relative paths or something else altogether. I'm not sure what an absolute path should be. Right now I'm working on localhost, but won't always be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, argh. The issue was the comma near the end of the line "var tinyMCEImageList =..."

Now it works fine with the relative urls starting with /media

The clue was given by Firebug Console, which showed me the js error. I just happened to click there, but will be using that a lot from now on!

Comment: firebug saves lots of time !